# How to sort this text file in descending order in python?

Tags: python, file, sorting

My text file is laid out as:

```
Richard 3 1 5
Jeff 3 7 4
Arnold 2 1 9
```

I have isolated the highest of these scores by using the following code and rewritten it:

```
with open ('class1.txt', 'r') as f, open("class11.txt", 'w') as fout:
      lines = [line.strip() for line in f]
      for line in lines:
           splitted = [i for i in line.split(' ') if i]
           nums = splitted[1:]
           max_nums = max(map(int, nums))
           name = splitted[0]
           fout.write(str(max_nums) + (' ') + (name) + ('\n'))
           print (splitted)
```

The above code swaps the two columns now so the highest number is first for example

```
9 Arnold
```

I need to now sort these numbers in descending order. I have tried many ways such as reading the lines and using the reversed function but I get lots of `\` when I run it?

Comment: Can you include actual and expected output in the question? In general, I would keep the data  (max number + name) in a list, sort that, and write only once afterwards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than write out the data immediately, append the data as tuples to a list, then sort that list. *Then* write out the data.

Reimplementing your reading loop to create that list:

```
entries = []
with open ('class1.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        row = line.split()
        if not row:
            continue
        name = row[0]
        max_score = max(map(int, row[1:]))
        entries.append((max_score, name))

with open("class11.txt", 'w') as fout:
    for max_score, name in sorted(entries, reverse=True):
        fout.write('{} {}\n'.format(max_score, name)
```

Rather than use `line.strip()` and `line.split(' ')`, I used the 0-argument `str.split()` version which includes a strip and splits on *arbitrary width* whitespace; this simplifies the per-line handling.

Sorting is done using the [`sorted()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted); setting `reverse=True` reverses the sort order so the highest score is listed first. Because `entries` is a list of tuples, these tuples are sorted in lexicographical order; two tuples are compared on their first element first (the score), and if two entries have the same score, the second element (the name) determines the sort order.

This does mean that entries with equal score are then sorted on the name in reverse alphabetical order. If this is an issue, you'll need to use a more complex sort key:

```
sorted(entries, key=lambda t: (-t[0], t[1]))
```

The `key` is then applied to each tuple to determine the value to sort on; by sorting *forward* on negative scores you still place the highest score first, but in case of a tie names are still sorted in forward alphabetical order.

Sorting demo to illustrate the difference; the two "names" with score 6 switch position:

```
>>> entries = [(5, 'foo'), (6, 'eggs'), (7, 'spam'), (6, 'bar')]
>>> sorted(entries, reverse=True)
[(7, 'spam'), (6, 'eggs'), (6, 'bar'), (5, 'foo')]
>>> sorted(entries, key=lambda t: (-t[0], t[1]))
[(7, 'spam'), (6, 'bar'), (6, 'eggs'), (5, 'foo')]
```

If you wanted to sort the already produced output file, you'd have to read it in again, split each line, convert the first element to an integer and apply the same sort and write loop afterwards.

Comment: Beautiful so efficent as well!!!